# Joomla administrator URL error

Tags: admin, joomla3.0

I am facing a very strange error. I searched a lot about this, tried a lot of fixes, but nothing seems to work.

The front end is fine, but the administrator does not show up ([link to my site’s admin section](http://www.parquet.disegnarecasa.com/Administrator/)). It says site cannot be reached.

The error log says:

> Username and password does not match or you do not have an account yet.

As far as I know right now, I have checked .htaccess, configuration.php and even tried disabling all the system plugins. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you normally use /Administrator/ but on the off chance you don't, the address to the administrator folder is usually case-sensitive and that could be your problem.